# Channel for Report Command

Tags: python

I have my bot code for a report command but i am wanting it to put everything in the channel the command was in

```
@bot.command()
async def report(ctx):
    a_list = []
    submit_channel = bot.get_channel(889700840913371166)
    channel = await ctx.author.create_dm()

    def check(m):
        return m.content is not None and m.channel == channel

    for question in q_list:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await channel.send(question)
        msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
        a_list.append(msg.content)

    submit_wait = True
    while submit_wait:
        await channel.send('End of questions - "submit" to finish')
        msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
        if "submit" in msg.content.lower():
            submit_wait = False
            answers = "\n".join(f'{a}. {b}' for a, b in enumerate(a_list, 1))
            submit_msg = f'Application from {msg.author} \nThe answers are:\n{answers}'
            await submit_channel.send(submit_msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know if this is what your asking. But to send a message to the channel where the command was originally sent, you would do:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def report(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Message to the original channel!")
```

Also, I would like to add that the discord.py library is archived so changes to the api in the future might make discord.py not function.